# file_existe nao encontra arquivo

Tags: php

estou com um problema ao usar a função do php que verifica se algum arquivo existe em um diretório usando o file_exists mais sempre retorna false mesmo o arquivo estando no diretório alguém teria uma solução para isso

```html
$filename = 'http://megaki/uploads/windows/thumb.jpg';
     if (file_exists($filename)) {
         echo 'O arquivo existe no diretorio.';
          } else {
           echo 'O arquivo não existe nesse diretorio.';
              }
```

lembrando a imagem existe no diretório windows mais ao executar retorna a menssagem  do else que o arquivo não pode ser encontrado estou usando servidor local wampserver

Comment: ja tentou utilizar $_SERVER[ 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ] para obter o caminho absoluto do arquivo e ver se dessa forma funciona?

Comment: obrigado usando o caminho absoluto funcionou

Comment: Esse seu link está estranho não seria megaki.com?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você Pode usar a Constante Magica

```
__DIR__
```

(Retorna o caminho até o arquivo php em que está inserida) e percorrer até o caminho do arquivo solicitado. Exemplo:

```
file_exists(__DIR__.'/caminho/para/o/arquivo');
```

Comment: dessa maneira tambem deu certo